# Find nearby stores React Native

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native, redux

I have a React Native app that uses SQL as a data store, so I have a relational database and a table for stores. Each store has a column for its latitude position and its longitude position.

I want to implement a 'find stores nearby' feature. I have users current position sitting in my Redux store.

How do I go about doing something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly generic and broad, and your specific implementation details will change depending on the database used to store your SQL data. But if you're using MySQL, then [Geo Distance Search with MySQL](https://www.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) should get you pointed in the right direction.